# Linq to SQL Multiple Table Select as Keyvalue Pair

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am struggling to return a set of results to an automplete plugin as a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Below is my current select statement

```
var fetchStudents = (from tg in dc.TEACHINGGROUPs
     from sg in dc.STUGROUPs
         .Where(sg => sg.GroupId == tg.GroupId)
         .DefaultIfEmpty()
     where sg.SetId == strSetId && tg.LecturerId == strLecturerID
     from stu in dc.STUDENTRECORDs
         .Where(stu => stu.StudentId == sg.StudentId)
         .DefaultIfEmpty()
         where stu.Name.StartsWith(name)
     select new { studentName = stu.Name, studentID = stu.StudentId }).Distinct();
```

Is there a way that I can select each result as a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` so that I can return the resultset in the correct format? I have a feeling it is staring me in the face but have been at it for hours and my brain is broken..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from …
 select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(stu.Name, stu.StudentId))
    .Distinct().ToList()
```